# Django models for create table

Tags: django-models

I am working on creating model in models.py file.

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=False,default='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

above code working perfect as it create default in database as per mentioned.

```
concept_id  = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)
```

above code not working as it can't able to create default value.

please help me for assign default value for above mentioned field.

Also How can i create Double Type using models.py ?? by using above code i am creating integer type field but can't create Double dataType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DecimalField. Ie

```
models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

or a FloatField (Decimal is more precise, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield-vs-decimalfield).